# Getting only the filename out of the path with GetOpenFileName

Tags: c++, windows, c++-cli

So I have this code:

```cpp
        OPENFILENAME ofn;

        char file_name[100];

        ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(OPENFILENAME));

        ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(OPENFILENAME);
        ofn.hwndOwner = NULL;
        ofn.lpstrFile = file_name;
        ofn.lpstrFile[0] = '\0';
        ofn.nMaxFile = 100;
        ofn.lpstrFilter = "Dynamic Link Libraries (.dll)\0*.dll";
        ofn.nFilterIndex = 1;

        GetOpenFileName(&ofn);
        cout << (const char*)ofn.lpstrFile << endl;
```

Which simply defines propreties for windows to then open a file with `GetOpenFileName(&ofn)`, but when I print the `lpstrFile` I get the full path of the file I selected.

Now my question is, How on c++ can I only get the file name ex `file.dll` and not `C:/hello/file.dll` out of `ofn.lpstrFile` using either text replacement functions or in-built windows functions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [PathStripPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-pathstrippatha) would probably do what you seem to want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it by using the `std::filesystem::path` class:

```
std::filesystem::path myFile = ofn.lpstrFile;
std::filesystem::path fullname = myFile.filename();

cout << fullname.c_str() << endl;
```

And it also works with the method pointed out by @WhozCraig:

```cpp
#pragma comment(lib, "shlwapi.lib")
#include <Shlwapi.h>

PathStripPath(ofn.lpstrFile);
```